# Year function in Lubridate is not only taking the year as planned

Tags: r, lubridate

I have been trying to use the year function in lubridate to extract only the year from a date, but it is still keeping the entire date. Can anyone help me fix this issue please?

```
        data %>% 
        select(ID, Author, Date, Location, Treatment) %>%     
        distinct() %>%
        drop_na() %>%   
        mutate(year = lubridate::year(Date)) %>% 
        unite('Study', Author, Date, Location, sep = " ", remove = T, na.rm = F) %>% 
        flextable() %>% 
        autofit()
  
           }
```

Comment: We have no idea what `data` looks like or what the class of column `Date` is. Please post your data by copying the output of `dput(data)`, or if you have a large data set `dput(head(data))`, into your question.

Comment: Check the datatype of Date. {lubridate}  is pretty tolerant, e.g. if you define a string, e.g. `mydate <- "2019-05-28"` and then run `lubridate::year(mydate)` you misteriously get `2019`. However, it is better style to coerce dates in the appropriate format, e.g. `mydate <- lubridate::ymd(mydate)`. This way R knows that you want to work with a date.

Comment: @Ray - I think you mean `lubridate::ymd(mydate)`...

Comment: @Limey thanks for spotting this. Corrected my previous comment. a moral +1 for you!

Comment: @LMc I apologize, I cannot really share the data.

Comment: @Ray, the datatype of Date is character. I am trying to use your code to make sure its in a date format and then extract just the year, but not having any luck. I appreciate everyone's help!

Comment: @Sophia That's okay, I understand data can be sensitive. You have shared the class of your column which is helpful. Can you post a value or two from that column so we can understand how the string looks?

Comment: @LMc thank you for understanding, yes, the dates appear as ```[1] "1999-01-01" "1999-01-01" "1999-01-01" "1999-01-01" "1999-01-01" "1999-01-01"```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that `class(data$Dates)` is a character column. It needs to be of class `"Date"` for `year` to understand which part is the year.

The default formats that `as.Date` check when passed a string are: `c("%Y-%m-%d", "%Y/%m/%d")`, which match the format your character column is in (e.g. YYYY-numeric month-day).

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
  mutate(year = year(as.Date(Dates)))
```

**Output**

```
       Dates year
1 1999-01-01 1999
2 1999-01-01 1999
3 1999-01-01 1999
4 1999-01-01 1999
5 1999-01-01 1999
6 1999-01-01 1999
```

**Data**

```
data <- structure(list(Dates = c("1999-01-01", "1999-01-01", "1999-01-01", 
"1999-01-01", "1999-01-01", "1999-01-01")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```